# How to plot categorical data with seaborn setting the plot-style for each data column?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

### Background

Let's say I have the following dataset:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = ([["Cheese", x] for x in np.random.normal(0.8, 0.03, 10)] + 
        [["Meat", x] for x in np.random.normal(0.4, 0.05, 14)] + 
        [["Bread", 0.8], ["Bread", 0.65]])

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["Food", "Score"])


import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sns.set(style="ticks", color_codes=True)
sns.set_context("paper")
sns.catplot(x="Score", y="Food", kind="box", data=df)
```

which yields the following plot (or similar, depending on the generated random numbers):

[image: Sample box plot]

The reason I am going for box-plots with my actual data is that individual dots combined with the amount of categories I want to show make the plot visually way too noisy and the boxes give a nice general overview of how the data is distributed which is what I am after. However, the issue is with categories like the "Bread" category.

### Question

As you can observe, seaborn produced boxes with median, quartiles etc. for all three categories. However, since the category "Bread" does only have two data-points, using a box-plot for this category is not really an appropriate representation. I would much rather have *this category only* as individual dots.

But when looking at the examples on the https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/categorical.html, the only suggestion for combining box-plots and simple dots is to plot *both* for all categories which is not what I am after.

**In short:** How do I plot categorical data with seaborn, selecting the appropriate representation for each category?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try creating df for bread and not bread:

```
dfb = df[df['Food'].notnull() & (df['Food'] == 'Bread')]
dfnot_b = df[df['Food'].notnull() & (df['Food'] != 'Bread')]
```

then add another axis:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax.twinx()
```

try different plots:

```
sns.boxplot(x="Score", y="Food", data=dfnot_b, ax=ax)
sns.stripplot(x="Score", y="Food", data=dfb, ax=ax2)
```

[image: plot overlay]

Comment: Nice idea with the second axis. Though now the "Bread" category isn't given any vertical space.

Comment: @NOhs In the `sns.boxplot` function you can set `width=0.2` to make some space.